# Erro ao ler arquivo txt linha por linha

Tags: java, array

Estou com problema para ler o arquivo dist1.txt e conseguir passar os valores de cada linha e passar para uma matriz da outra classe.

O arquivo tem o seguinte formato .txt:

```
1;1;00
1;2;14
1;3;05
1;4;05
1;5;12
1;6;15
2;1;14
2;2;00
2;3;07
2;4;08
2;5;09
2;6;10
3;1;05
3;2;07
3;3;00
3;4;12
3;5;21
3;6;14
4;1;05
4;2;08
4;3;12
4;4;00
4;5;15
4;6;16
5;1;12
5;2;09
5;3;21
5;4;16
5;5;00
5;6;02
6;1;15
6;2;10
6;3;14
6;4;16
6;5;02
6;6;00
```

Essa é a minha classe principal.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static File file;
    static Graph subway = new Graph(6);
    static int[][] a = new int[6][6];
    private static final int S1 = 1;
    private static final int S2 = 6;

    /***
     * <h1>Metodo de leitura de arquivos</h1>
     * @param filePath - caminho absoluto do arquivo no sistema
     * @return - Para este caso, retorna uma matriz 6 x 6 somente com o peso de cada rota
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println("Desenvolvido por Guilherme alves vieria dos santos");
      System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.print("Digite o nome do arquivo: ");
      System.out.println();

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String arquivo = in.next();

        Main.file = new File(arquivo);

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(Main.file);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                    String[] dadosLinha = sc.nextLine().split(";");
                    a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[2]);


//O problema parece que está aqui 
subway.makeEdge(Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[0]),Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[1]),Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[2]));

                  }
            }
            sc.close();
            //return a;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Arquivo nao encontrado, verifique se o caminho do arquivo esta correto");
        } 

        while (true) {
            //int source = readStation("source", in);
            //int destination = readStation("destination", in);

            System.out.println("Caminho mais rapido:");
            for (Integer station : subway.path(1/*source*/, 6/*destination*/)) {
                System.out.println((station+1) + " -> ");
            }
            System.out.println("EXIT");
        }
    }

    private static int readStation(String type, Scanner in) {

      while (true) {
           System.out.println(type + ":");
           String line = in.nextLine().trim();
           if (line.isEmpty()) {
               System.out.println("Linha vazia!");
               System.exit(0);
           }
           try {
               int station = Integer.parseInt(line);
               if (station >= 1 && station <= 6) return station-1;
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           }
           System.out.println("Invalid station! Try again.");
       }
     }
}
```

A minha outra classe é o `Graph` que faço a lógica para fazer a leitura do grafo.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Graph {
    private static final int UNDEFINED = -1;
    private int vertices[][];

    public Graph(int numVertices) {
        vertices = new int[numVertices][numVertices];
    }

    public void makeEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2, int time) {
        vertices[vertex1][vertex2] = time;
        vertices[vertex2][vertex1] = time;
    }

    public void removeEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2) {
        vertices[vertex1][vertex2] = 0;
        vertices[vertex2][vertex1] = 0;
    }

    public int getCost(int vertex1, int vertex2) {
        return vertices[vertex1][vertex2];
    }

    /**
     * @param vertex Origin vertex
     * @return a list with the index of all vertexes connected to the given vertex.
     */
    public List<Integer> getNeighbors(int vertex) {
        List<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices[vertex].length; i++)
            if (vertices[vertex][i] > 0) {
                neighbors.add(i);
            }

        return neighbors;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of the Dijkstra's algorithm.
     * @param from Source node
     * @param to Destionation node
     * @return The path.
     */
    public List<Integer> path(int from, int to) {
        //Initialization
        //--------------
        int cost[] = new int[vertices.length];
        int prev[] = new int[vertices.length];
        Set<Integer> unvisited = new HashSet<>();

        //The initial node has cost 0 and no previous vertex
        cost[from] = 0;

        //All other nodes will have its cost set to MAXIMUM and undefined previous
        for (int v = 0; v < vertices.length; v++) {
            if (v != from) {
                cost[v] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            prev[v] = UNDEFINED;
            unvisited.add(v);
        }

        //Graph search
        //------------
        while (!unvisited.isEmpty()) {
            int near = closest(cost, unvisited);
            unvisited.remove(near);

            for (Integer neighbor : getNeighbors(near)) {
                int totalCost = cost[near] + getCost(near, neighbor);
                if (totalCost < cost[neighbor]) {
                    cost[neighbor] = totalCost;
                    prev[neighbor] = near;
                }
            }
            //Found?
            if (near == to) {
                return makePathList(prev, near);
            }
        }

        //No path found
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    private int closest(int[] dist, Set<Integer> unvisited) {
        double minDist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minIndex = 0;
        for (Integer i : unvisited) {
            if (dist[i] < minDist) {
                minDist = dist[i];
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minIndex;
    }

    private List<Integer> makePathList(int[] prev, int u) {
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
        path.add(u);
        while (prev[u] != UNDEFINED) {
            path.add(prev[u]);
            u = prev[u];
        }
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=csv+java

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que no arquivo você considera que os nós são numerados de 1 a 6 enquanto que utiliza os índices numerados de 0 a 5. Até há alguns lugares onde você usa `+1` ou `-1` por causa disso, mas não usa em todos os lugares que deveria. Utilizando verificações nos parâmetros de `Graph` isso ficaria óbvio.

No entanto, há mais umas outras coisinhas que poderiam ser melhoradas no seu código. Em especial que variáveis globais são ruins, que não tem porque usar `System.exit` e você tem javadoc mal-formado. E também é muito mais fácil ler todas as linhas do arquivo usando o [método `Files.readAllLines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)).

Eis o código revisado:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph subway = new Graph(6);

        System.out.println("Desenvolvido por Guilherme alves vieria dos santos");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Digite o nome do arquivo: ");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String arquivo = in.next();

        try {
            for (String linha : Files.readAllLines(new File(arquivo).toPath())) {
                String[] dadosLinha = linha.split(";");
                if (dadosLinha.length != 3) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                int a = Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[0]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[1]);
                int c = Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[2]);
                subway.makeEdge(a - 1, b - 1, c - 1);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Arquivo não encontrado, verifique se o caminho do arquivo está correto.");
            return;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("O arquivo contém dados malformados.");
            return;
        }

        while (true) {
            //int source = readStation("source", in);
            //int destination = readStation("destination", in);

            System.out.println("Caminho mais rápido: ");
            for (Integer station : subway.path(0/*source*/, 5/*destination*/)) {
                System.out.println((station + 1) + " -> ");
            }
            System.out.println("EXIT");
        }
    }

    private static int readStation(String type, Scanner in) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(type + ": ");
            String line = in.nextLine().trim();
            try {
                int station = Integer.parseInt(line);
                if (station >= 1 && station <= 6) return station - 1;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Ignora.
            }
            System.out.println("Invalid station! Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Graph {
    private static final int UNDEFINED = -1;
    private int vertices[][];

    public Graph(int numVertices) {
        if (numVertices < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        vertices = new int[numVertices][numVertices];
    }

    private void checkVertex(int vertex) {
        if (vertex < 0 || vertex >= vertices.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    public void makeEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2, int time) {
        checkVertex(vertex1);
        checkVertex(vertex2);
        if (time < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        vertices[vertex1][vertex2] = time;
        vertices[vertex2][vertex1] = time;
    }

    public void removeEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2) {
        checkVertex(vertex1);
        checkVertex(vertex2);
        vertices[vertex1][vertex2] = 0;
        vertices[vertex2][vertex1] = 0;
    }

    public int getCost(int vertex1, int vertex2) {
        checkVertex(vertex1);
        checkVertex(vertex2);
        return vertices[vertex1][vertex2];
    }

    /**
     * @param vertex Origin vertex
     * @return a list with the index of all vertexes connected to the given vertex.
     */
    public List<Integer> getNeighbors(int vertex) {
        checkVertex(vertex);
        List<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices[vertex].length; i++) {
            if (vertices[vertex][i] > 0) {
                neighbors.add(i);
            }
        }

        return neighbors;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of the Dijkstra's algorithm.
     * @param from Source node
     * @param to Destionation node
     * @return The path.
     */
    public List<Integer> path(int from, int to) {
        checkVertex(from);
        checkVertex(to);
        //Initialization
        //--------------
        int cost[] = new int[vertices.length];
        int prev[] = new int[vertices.length];
        Set<Integer> unvisited = new HashSet<>();

        //All other nodes will have its cost set to MAXIMUM and undefined previous
        for (int v = 0; v < vertices.length; v++) {
            cost[v] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            prev[v] = UNDEFINED;
            unvisited.add(v);
        }

        //The initial node has cost 0 and no previous vertex
        cost[from] = 0;

        //Graph search
        //------------
        while (!unvisited.isEmpty()) {
            int near = closest(cost, unvisited);
            unvisited.remove(near);

            for (Integer neighbor : getNeighbors(near)) {
                int totalCost = cost[near] + getCost(near, neighbor);
                if (totalCost < cost[neighbor]) {
                    cost[neighbor] = totalCost;
                    prev[neighbor] = near;
                }
            }
            //Found?
            if (near == to) {
                return makePathList(prev, near);
            }
        }

        //No path found
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    private int closest(int[] dist, Set<Integer> unvisited) {
        double minDist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minIndex = 0;
        for (Integer i : unvisited) {
            if (dist[i] < minDist) {
                minDist = dist[i];
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minIndex;
    }

    private List<Integer> makePathList(int[] prev, int u) {
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
        path.add(u);
        while (prev[u] != UNDEFINED) {
            path.add(prev[u]);
            u = prev[u];
        }
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ainda estou com problemas par ler cada linha.